# How to replace document from one to another collection

Tags: angular, firebase

I added a review to the collection "reviews_unchecked". The administrator must confirm them. So I decided to create another collection with verified reviews and after confirmation, the review will be added to the "confirmed" and removed from the "unchecked".

my review service

```
review: any;
  uncheckedReviewCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  confirmedReviewCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;
  reviewDocument: AngularFirestoreDocument<any>;

  constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore) {
    this.uncheckedReviewCollection = this.afs.collection('reviews_unchecked');
    this.confirmedReviewCollection = this.afs.collection<Review>('reviews');
   }

   getData(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.uncheckedReviewCollection
      .snapshotChanges()
      .pipe(map((actions) => {
        return actions.map((a) => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return {id, ...data };
        });
      })
      );
  }

  getReview(id) {
    this.reviewDocument = this.afs.doc<any>('reviews_unchecked/' + id);
    this.review = this.reviewDocument.valueChanges();
    return this.review;
  }

  deleteReview(id: string) {
    return this.afs.doc<any>(`reviews_unchecked/${id}`).delete();
  }

  confirmedReview(id) {
    this.confirmedReviewCollection.add(this.review);
    return this.afs.doc<any>(`reviews_unchecked/${id}`).delete();
  }

}
```

my component

```
  review: any;
  reviews: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(
    private reviewsService: ReviewsService,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.reviews = this.reviewsService.getData();
  }
  deleteReview(id: string) {
    this.reviewsService.deleteReview(id);
  }
  confirmedReview(id: string) {
    this.reviewsService.confirmedReview(id);
  }
```

Why i have this error and how to fix it:
ERROR FirebaseError: "Function CollectionReference.add() requires its first argument to be of type object, but it was: a custom Observable object"

Answer (score 0):

When adding a document, it has to be of type `object` and it cannot be an instance of a class, therefore you either need to create a separate interface or class or use `JSON.parse()` to change it to an object.

You can check the following GitHub issues:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/issues/1335

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/311

---

Try the following:

```
confirmedReview(id) {
let firestoreData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.review));
this.confirmedReviewCollection.add(firestoreData);
return this.afs.doc<any>(`reviews_unchecked/${id}`).delete();
}
```

From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

> The `JSON.parse()` method parses a JSON string, constructing the JavaScript value or object described by the string